# Android emulator starts but doesn't run my app

Tags: java, android

Everything works perfectly yesterday, but now my emulator is broken. Emulator starts without erros but app doesn't launch. I tried to install my app from apk file, but it doesn't work too(see the screen). Also I tried to run default android studio project and it gives me the same problem.

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7eP2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I solved this problem of deleting the folder **.android** and redownloading AVD.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).